Angular Testing Error when there is Class[].push
let's say I have firstComponent that already have success ng test. in the test Im doing some test related to router and have this line
const mockRouter = jasmine.createSpyObj("Router", ["navigateByUrl"]);
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
  ],
  declarations: [firstComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
  ]

and I need to add someClass[] so in the component I add this
list: someClass[] = [];
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.list.push({},{},{});
...

after I add code above the unit test error and i got this error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')

but when I comment / remove this.list.push() code the ng test is success

please share the full test case, also share the error stack trace! there is no root in the code you shared!

Hi, the problem is when i comment / remove the this.list.push() line in the component, all test case will success, ill try to give the test case later when im back to work
